# Python Question have trouble saving data from website to .txt file

Tags: python, fwrite

I am having problems writing the original data I scraped from the website to a txt.file in Python. I have looked through different questions here but I still have not been able to get my code to work. Any suggestions? I can get it to print what I want but for the life of me cannot figure out how to simply write it to a .txt file.

```
#PACKAGES WE WILL NEED FOR THIS PROJECT
import csv
import re
import requests
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse

#CREATE VARIABLE FOR LINK TO PAGE WE WILL WEBSCRAPE
base_censuspage = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"

#EXTRACT DATA FROM WEBPAGE
r = requests.get(base_censuspage)
htmlcontent = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,'html.parser')
links_array = []

#FIND LINKS TO OTHER PAGES AND ADD THEM TO LIST
for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href':re.compile(r'html')}):
    links_array.append(urljoin(base_censuspage,link.get('href')))

#REMOVE DUPLICATES AND PRINT LIST TO VERIFY DUPLICATES WERE REMOVED
unique_links = set(links_array)
pprint.pprint(unique_links)
pprint.pprint(htmlcontent)

#SAVE TO CSV FILE
with open("C996PROJECTASSESSMENTCSVFILE.CSV","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
    wr.writerow(links_array)

#SAVE TO TXT FILE
with open('webscrapeddata.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(htmlcontent)
```

Comment: What exactly happens? Is the file present? If so, what does it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the program and the `UnicodeEncodeError` that was being thrown happened because the encoding method of the `htmlcontent` was not the same as the open files in python
so to solve that just add an encoding argument as following:

```
#SAVE TO TXT FILE
with open('webscrapeddata.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f: # <-- HERE
    f.write(htmlcontent)
```